# Python code - I'm stuck - recursion

Tags: python, algorithm

I need some help because I think I'm lost. I've search before in this site and of course I've Google it, but believe me that if it was so simple to me, I haven't ask it at all, so please be kind to me.
I'm new to python and coding isn't that easy to me.

Anyway, take a look at my code:

```
def coin_problem(price, cash_coins):
    if (price < 0):
        return []
    if (price == 0):
        return [[]]

    options = []

    for a_coin in cash_coins:
        coins_minus_coin = cash_coins[:]
        coins_minus_coin.remove(a_coin)
        sub_coin_problem = coin_problem (price - a_coin, cash_coins)
        for coin in sub_coin_problem:
            coin.append(a_coin)
        options.extend(sub_coin_problem)

    return options

print coin_problem(4, [1, 2])
```

As you can see, I've tried to deal with the famous coin problem by recursion (and as I wrote before, I know many have already asked about this, I read their questions and the answers but I still couldn't understand the fully solutions).

This code was made by me, all of it. And now I'm stuck and confused. When the value of "price" is 4 and the value of "cash_coins" is [1,2] instead of returning something like this:

```
[1,1,1,1]
[2,2]
[2,1,1]
```

I get something more like:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

the combination of "2" and the double "1" repeats 3 times instead of "1".
I don't know what should I do in order to fix the problem or to improve my code so it will work better.

Comment: I dont see the recursion, but I do see you using `cash_coins` as both an iterable and a function.

Comment: cmd:
Indeed, my mistake. check again. What about now?

Mr E:
again, my mistake. check again.

Comment: Is `cash_problem` supposed to be `coin_problem`?

Comment: Indeed. Sorry about all my mistakes... hope it's my last one.

Comment: There's no need to ask us if it works now. Just make sure we can run your code to produce the claimed problem! Underneath the definition of `coin_problem` add a line like `print coin_problem(4, [1, 2])` and make it so that if I copy and paste the entire block of code into my Python interpreter I get your `[[[.....]]]` output. If it crashes or doesn't produce the claimed output then fix it. It's OK to be stuck but there's little sense in supplying broken code!

Comment: You are right, Mr E. Defently, but I'm so tired of this code! I'm lost!!!

Comment: OK guys, give me 5 min to edit the code again but this time correctly so it will be fine (I mean, no bugs or errors). Please come again within 5 min and check the code again.

Comment: @MrE "Indentation"? What do you mean?

Comment: I've fixed it and added the line to call the code. The body of the function wasn't indented. What's there now is a "complete" example. I can directly run this code and begin to see what the problems are without having to edit it first or guess at anything. It's a good idea to put in a few minutes of work to present your problem in this way in the future :)

Comment: You should not remove your question once it is answered, the whole concept of SO is to build the library of questions ans solutions, it is not the chat room just for your problem fixing but open library for many future visitors

Comment: On StackOverflow we don't delete questions when they're answered - we leave them up so other people can learn from them too. You can delete it yourself if you really want, but please consider leaving it.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to add a single item to a list, use `append`. When you want to combine two lists together, use `extend`.

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

```
    coins_minus_coin = cash_coins[:]
    coins_minus_coin.remove(coin)
```

You never use this variable.

```
    for i in sub_coins:
        i.append(coin)
    cash_coins_options.append(sub_coins)
```

You never use `i` either. I'd guess you meant:

```
    for i in sub_coins:
        i.append(coin)
        cash_coins_options.append(i)
```

That solves the problem of stange results, but your solution will still only find `[]`. Why? Your recursion can only stop on a `return []`; it can't handle another fundamental case when you can tell the price using a single coin. Try adding at the top this simple condition:

```
# actually I changed my mind-
# I assume you're learning so try this one yourself :-)
```

This will cause your function to behave much better:

```
>>> print coin_problem(4, [1,2])
[[2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

which manages to produce correct answers (even though it duplicates some of them).

Comment: I liked it more before :-) You mostly renamed variables, I did the same with your new version and got the same result.